# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPLIANCE-FAQ\resources\views\respones\show.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have 4 tables (users, ask_questions, respones, categories).
I'm trying to show each response done asked question but i'm getting this error:
**Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPLIANCE-FAQ\resources\views\respones\show.blade.php)**

the model respone.php

```
{
    public $table = 'respones';

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'category_id',
        'author_name',
        'text_answer',
        'author_email_id',
        'ask_question_id',
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Respone::Observe(new \App\Observers\ResponeObserver );

    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function author_email()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_email_id');
    }

    public function ask_question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AskQuestion::class, 'ask_question_id');
    }
}
```

AskQuestion.php

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
];

protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'text_question',
    'objet_question',
    'assigned_to_user_id',
];

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    AskQuestion::Observe(new \App\Observers\AskQuestionObserver );

    static::addGlobalScope(new CollaborateurScope);
}

/**
* In this method may be it should belongsto instead of hasmany
*/
public function respones()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Respone::class, 'ask_question_id', 'id');
}

public function assigned_to_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to_user_id');
}
```

User.php

```
public function askQuestionRespones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Respone::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

show.blade.php

```
               <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Thématique') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ $respone->category->name }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Nom auteur') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ $respone->author_name }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Auteur email') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ $respone->author_email->email }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Question') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ $respone->ask_question->text_question }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Réponse') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ $respone->text_answer }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

ResponesController.php for the admin part

```
public function show(Respone $respone)
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('respone_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    $respone->load('category', 'author_email', 'ask_question');

    return view('admin.respones.show', compact('respone'));
}
```

ResponeController.php for the front part

```
public function show(Respone $respone, Category $category,
                     User $user, AskQuestion $ask_question)
{
    $respone->load('author_email', 'category', 'ask_question');

    $ask_question->load('Respones');

    return view('respones.show', compact('respone', 'ask_question'));
}
```

Comment: Could you add your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of these relations is returning null

```
$respone->category
$respone->ask_question
$respone->author_email
```

so when you try to access a property on the empty relation (on the null value null->attribute), you receive this error.

you can try check the value of each relation before echoing the the attribute, with `@if` or `@isset`

```php
@if($respone->category)

@endif
```

or wrap the relations with the `optional` helper

```php
<th>
    {{ trans('Thématique') }}
</th>
<td>
    {{ optional($respone->category)->name }}
</td>
```

Comment: You're right when i do a dd($respone)Respone
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "author_email" => null
    "category" => null
    "ask_question" => null
  ]

Comment: I think the problem come from my tables relationships or not ?

Comment: You will need to share you database structure and model relations, but this is another subject, if the error is gone please mark this as solved and open another thread.

Comment: Yes the error is gone but nothing appear on my blade page the data i'm biding for

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `null coalescing operator ??` ( introduced in PHP 7). It's used to check if the value is set or null, or in other words, if the value exists and not null, then it returns the first operand, otherwise, it returns the second operand."

```
<td>
  {{ $respone->category->name ?? 'Default' }} 
</td>
```

Comment: when i used the use the null coalescing operator ?? the error disepear but it return no data

Comment: Add it to your post